# Find the diff between a database and a mysql file

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database and a mysql file of the same database with some modifications(Some tables might have been added, some might have been dropped, table structures, some tables definitions might have been changed). How to find the changes between the two databases and their tables using `PHP` (structure only)?

Comment: Using just PHP you can't without making a full script to compare.  What have you tried?

Comment: I tried importing the making a temp database using the mysql file and then using mysql queries to find the required data, but finding some problems in that. Also, I want to know, if there is a way to do it without importing the database

Answer (score 0):

Here is a MySQL procedure that does exactly that: http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/qrytip.php?id=624

Hope it helps (PS: there are a lot of useful queries here: www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php )

PS: To get the data in PHP, just run the query and grab the info, then do whatever you want with it.

PS2: Import your old database dump into another database, and then use this procedure to compare the databases.

Answer (score 0):

I've done this sort of some time ago. It boils down to having two databases, dump them to a file and then compare them with `diff`, adjusted for known differences like database names.

There are also tools out there that can do this interactively by querying two databases and allowing to sync differences.

I don't know of a tool that compares a dump file with a database, though.